# QTableWidget consumes CPU

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qtablewidget, packet-capture

I am working on a packet sniffer with C++, using QT for the user interface.

I have two main threads: QT's main thread, and another thread that takes care of the packet capture and processing.

The capture thread captures and processes the packets -> it then sends the result to the GUI thread which displays it using the signals and slots mechanism.

I am using a QTableWidget to display the packets.

The problem is that when I have a massive flow of packets (When downloading something for example) the program starts to lag and the program starts to eat a lot of CPU (Up to 17% during a download or a video)

Is there a solution to optimize a QTableWidget and make my program more fluid?

My QTableWidget:
[image: My QTableWidget]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to stop using QTableWidget and use a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) instead.  The difference between a QTableWidget and a QTableView is that a QTableWidget dynamically allocates a separate [QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html) object to hold the state of each cell; if you are creating and/or deleting a lot of cells in a short period of time (which it appears you are), the creation and/or deletion of all of these objects can be quite inefficient.

QTableView, on the other hand, doesn't require the creation of any per-cell QTableWidgetItem objects, which allows it to be more efficient when under heavy load.  Instead a QTableView has to consult a model-object, and the model object tells the QTableView what data to display at any given moment.  You'll need to create your own subclass of [QAbstractTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) for your QTableView to consult with, and call [setModel()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setModel) on your QTableView object with a pointer to your model-object.

It's all a bit involved, so you will want to read through Qt's [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) on the subject and look at their [example-programs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html) before trying to implement your own.

I've used this approach to implement e.g. a log-view which sometimes has dozens-to-hundreds of log messages generated per second, and it works well once you've set up the model correctly.